# ip route multiple entries

Tags: networking, server, ip

I have a list of 60k CIDRs to block and I am planning to do this using the following command.

```
ip route add blackhole 1.0.1.0/24
```

Is there a way I can import the whole list on my **Ubuntu 18** server or is there any place where I can manually enter the entire list?

Is there a chance of the server becoming slow or unstable after adding 60k entries?

Comment: Why dont you just use iptables to block a range of ip's ?

Comment: @hellomoto Is it likely to create a performance issue if I user iptables / ipset / ip route with so many entries?

Comment: @hellomoto If you have 60k rules multiplied by 100k packets per seconds, that's a *lot* of comparisons per second... It may very well create a performance problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have them listed as one per line, it's trivial to script this:

```
for ip in $(cat filename.txt)
  do
   ip route add blackhole $ip
done
```

As hello moto said in a comment: why not use `iptables` to filter? To do that...

```
for ip in $(cat filename.txt)
 do
  iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j DROP
done
```

With 60k rules, I would have a look at [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/), to avoid crippling performance. If you have 60k rules and 100kpps, thats 60k*100k=6 billion comparisons per second...

[This documentation from Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ipset) is somewhat more friendly than the manpage for `ipset`, and the syntax applies for Ubuntu as well.

To use ipset:

```
ipset create blocklist
for ip in $(filename.txt)
 do
  ipset add blocklist $ip
done
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blocklist src -j DROP
```

In addition `iprange` may be useful. It takes a lists of subnets, and tries to merge networks into as few subnets as possible, which would reduce the number of comparisons needed.

Comment: are you suggesting ipset would be better than choosing ip route and iptables commands?

Comment: Yes. Ipset makes a hash table which enables cheaper look ups.

Comment: I am wondering, is it possible to block ASN instead of blocking individual CIDRs?

Comment: No. Ip packets does not carry information about asn.